# How to set latex table columns from the rightmost margin?

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, tabularx, columns

I want to display a table in latex. Currently I have the following situation.

```
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{#1}}

\begin{table}[h!]
\begin{tabularx}{0.45\textwidth}{P{3.2cm}*{5}{r}r} %{l*{5}{c}c}
\textbf{Statement}              & \textbf{P1} & \textbf{P2} & \textbf{P3} & \textbf{P4} & \textbf{P5} \\
\hline
The overall experience was enjoyable & 4 & 4 & 4 & 5 & 3  \\
Learning cricket was easy & 5 & 5 & 5 & 5 & 5 \\
\hline
\textit Cricket was user-friendly           & 3 & 3 & 4 & 4 &  2   \\
Using the bat was easy           & 5 & 4 & 5 & 5 & 4  \\
Using the balls was easy     & 5 & 5 & 4 & 3 &  4 \\
\hline
Cricket was easier than current system & 3 & 2 & 3 & 3 & 2 \\
I will play cricket in future & 3 & 4 & 4 & 4 & 3 \\
\end{tabularx}
\caption{Results from the questionnaire on 5-point Likert scale}
\label{tab:questionnaire}
\end{table}
```

[image]

The code outputs like the above. The problem is that, in two-column format, it leaves a lot of space on the right. I want my left most column to position from left, and all other columns to be positioned from the right. In that way, the white spaces will be minimized and the table will look decent. I have tried changing the column type. Doesn't work.

Any help is highly appreciated!

Comment: you should be using `tabular` not `tabularx` or use `X` not `p` columns (`tabularx` with no `X` columns does nothing useful)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have one column more than needed. I propose to use `tabularx` full column wide, and `ragged2e`. Added `booktabs` to have some vertical padding around horizontal rules, and reduced the value of `\tabcolsep`:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}%
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{array, tabularx, caption, booktabs}
\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]
\begin{table}[h!]
  \setlength\tabcolsep{3pt}
  \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{} >{\RaggedRight}X*{5}{c}@{}} %{l*{5}{c}c}
    \textbf{Statement} & \textbf{P1} & \textbf{P2} & \textbf{P3} & \textbf{P4} & \textbf{P5} \\
    \toprule
    The overall experience was enjoyable & 4 & 4 & 4 & 5 & 3 \\
    Learning cricket was easy & 5 & 5 & 5 & 5 & 5 \\
    \midrule
    \textit Cricket was user-friendly & 3 & 3 & 4 & 4 & 2 \\
    Using the bat was easy & 5 & 4 & 5 & 5 & 4 \\
    Using the balls was easy & 5 & 5 & 4 & 3 & 4 \\
    \midrule
    Cricket was easier than current system & 3 & 2 & 3 & 3 & 2 \\
    I will play cricket in future & 3 & 4 & 4 & 4 & 3 \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabularx}
  \caption{Results from the questionnaire on 5-point Likert scale}
  \label{tab:questionnaire}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Some suggestions:

- Instead of

  ```
  \newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
  ```

  use

  ```
  \newcolumntype{P}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}
  ```
- Instead of

  ```
  \begin{tabularx}{0.45\textwidth}{P{3.2cm}*{5}{r}r}
  ```

  use

  ```
  \centering
  \begin{tabularx}{0.6\textwidth}{@{}P *{5}{r} @{}}
  ```

  The `@{}` particles serve to remove the whitespace that's otherwise inserted at the left-hand and right-hand edges of the tabular matter.

A full MWE:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx,booktabs}
\newcolumntype{P}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h!]
\centering
\begin{tabularx}{0.6\textwidth}{@{}P *{5}{r} @{}}
\textbf{Statement}  & \textbf{P1} & \textbf{P2} & \textbf{P3} & \textbf{P4} & \textbf{P5} \\
\midrule
The overall experience was enjoyable & 4 & 4 & 4 & 5 & 3  \\
Learning cricket was easy & 5 & 5 & 5 & 5 & 5 \\
\midrule
\textit Cricket was user-friendly & 3 & 3 & 4 & 4 &  2 \\
Using the bat was easy       & 5 & 4 & 5 & 5 & 4  \\
Using the balls was easy     & 5 & 5 & 4 & 3 &  4 \\
\midrule
Cricket was easier than the current system & 3 & 2 & 3 & 3 & 2 \\
I will play cricket in the future & 3 & 4 & 4 & 4 & 3 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\caption{Results from the questionnaire on 5-point Likert scale}
\label{tab:questionnaire}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```